# How to write MYSQL query != in Codeigniter Active records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, oracle10g

I have the below query form using codeigniter active record function,

```
select * from user where user_id!=10
```

I have tried the below code

```
$condition=array(
'userr_id!='=>2,
);
$this->db-get('userd',$condition);
```

its return database error. How to make query using active record function?

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
$this->db->where("your_id !=",$your_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$condition=array(
                 'user_id !='=>$id
                );
$this->db->get('users',$condition);
```

or

```
$this->db->where("user_id !=",$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where("your_id <> ".$your_id);
```

`<>` refers to **NotEqual** in SQL.